# Collection format multi not supported in power apps

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, powerapps, swagger-2.0

While trying to connect to custom connector in power apps I am getting this error for pageable object, This is mainly coming for sort object in api specification. Is there any alternative for this. It's mandatory to use OpenApi2(Swagger Api) for us

Specified swagger has the following errors: 'Definition is not valid.
Error: 'Error : paths/~1api~1v3~random-api
-dates/get/parameters/9/collectionFormat :
The 'collectionFormat' keyword value 'Multi' is not supported. ## Error :